# Scala generics - why I can't create parametrised object inside generic class?

Tags: scala, jvm, jvm-languages

I'm currently learning scala.
Why this code doesn't work:

```
class GenClass[T](var d : T) {
  var elems: List[T] = Nil 
  def dosom(x: T) = { 
    var y = new T() 
    y   
  }
}
```

I get:
  *error: class type required but T found* 
in place of *var y - new T()*

Is it because type erasing from java? Is there any way to solve this - create variable of type T inside generic function?

Comment: Yup. It's a restriction from the Java roots. I usually use a "constructor function" (passed as ctor argument, for example), e.g. `() => T`, but there may be some way more nifty ways.

Comment: Yes - for me this solution look sufficient and simply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to instantiate an instance of type represented by type parameter in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305563/how-to-instantiate-an-instance-of-type-represented-by-type-parameter-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at this question, there's an example of a factory:
[How to instantiate an instance of type represented by type parameter in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305563/how-to-instantiate-an-instance-of-type-represented-by-type-parameter-in-scala)

Answer (score 2):

Because you can not be sure there always is a public, parameterless constructor.

Comment: That too +1. But in the general case there is know way of knowing *what* the run-time type of T is. Scala 2.8 introduces a "general" Manifest solution for this part of the problem.

Comment: Even if you have the manifest there is not necessarily a constructor with a given signature, or any; `T` might be a trait!

Comment: Yes - but the idea behind generic programming is to not solve everything (eg: type consistency). For example in C++ we can simply do everything with templates.