# How to pass a class as a parameter for instantiation in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to refactor an Akka application from a single tier to multi-tier structure with akka clustering (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/cluster-usage.html). Within the application are some actors that have a parameterized default constructor, e.g.

```
class MyActor(someParam: boolean = true) extends Actor {
    def receive = { /* message handling here... */ }
}
```

I am now trying to create a generic router actor that will route to a node with a specific node. The cluster configuration is working based of the example on the akka site, and I can create a router in 1 role that routes to the actor in another role:

```
class MyActorProxy extends Actor {
  val workerRouter = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props(classOf[MyActor]), name = "workerRouter")
  def receive = {
    case msg: Any =>
      val currentSender = sender()
      workerRouter.tell(msg, currentSender)
  }
}
```

This method works as needed. However, I need to go and create a handful of proxy classes with the same functionality, and it's painful. I'm trying to make it work better, and limited scala experience is making it difficult. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
abstract class RouterProxy[T <: Actor](routerPath: String) extends Actor {
  val router = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props(classOf[T])),name=routerPath)
  def receive = {
     case msg: Any => {
       val currentSender = sender()
       router.tell(msg,currentSender)
     }
  } 
}

class MyActorProxy extends RouterProxy[MyActor](routerPath = "myActorRouter")
```

Have come up with this by reading through some scala docs and through stackoverflow, but can't seem to get it right - this approach doesn't let me create the props for the actor. I've seen [How to instantiate an instance of type represented by type parameter in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305563/how-to-instantiate-an-instance-of-type-represented-by-type-parameter-in-scala) and I think that the type information is being lost (type erasure).

How would I go about passing an actor class to the router proxy to allow for router initialization?

This is the error I get during compilation, while initializing the router:

```
class type required but T found
```

**edit**

Background for using a generic proxy router

The reason for this approach is to refactor the application for both single tier and multi-tier architecture. When running multi-tier, I want to skip initializing any "heavy" actors. Given I have the following config on a frontend node:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /workerRouter {
    routee.paths = ["/user/myActor"]
    cluster.use-role = backend
  }
}

akka.cluster.roles = [frontend]
```

and the backend node has roles of `[backend]`, then when I start up frontend nodes, MyActor will not be initialized. MyActor is an example of 1 of many actors that are supervisors / managers. Each 1 of them might initialize a few other actors in turn (sometimes with routers). What I'm trying to do is refactor the application so I can run lightweight frontend nodes in a different tier to resource heavy backend nodes if I need to, but also still have the ability to run all on a single node. By this approach, I can add in initialization for heavy managers into my application bootstrap and add a role and it becomes a multifunctional app without needing recoding.

**edit 2** 
I am able to get the application to work as expected if the class constructor doesn't take any arguments.

```
MyActor extends Actor { /* ... */ }
```

And then in my abstract class:

```
abstract class RouterProxy[T <: Actor](routerPath: String) extends Actor {
  val router = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props[T]),name = routerPath)
}
```

`Props[MyActor]` works fine for a parameterless actor, but `Props(classOf[T])` looses the type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to define another class for the router, you can do it all through your configuration file:

```
val myActorRouter = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor]
      .withRouter(FromConfig())
      ,"workerRouter")
```

Where "workerRouter" is defined in your application.conf file like this:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /workerRouter {
    router = round-robin
    nr-of-instances = 5
  }
}
```

You can also configure it all through code if you have a pretty simple configuration:

```
val myActorRouter = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withRouter(
  RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 5)))
```

Either way you end up with `myActorRouter` as an actor ref you can send messages to.  In the background the Akka system has created a pool of `MyActor` actors and forwards the messages to them.  The router takes itself out of the response so you don't need to spoof the sender like you've done: when a routee sends a message to sender it goes directly back to the actor that sent the message to the router.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @gangstead - you are right, I can take that approach, but I want to be able to run a node without all the heavy components of `MyActor` being initialized (when using a multi-tier application).

I guess the question is not about why I'm building in a bit of redundancy, but more of a general Scala programming question: **How can I get around type erasure and preserve sub-class typing.**

Comment: Have you seen this?http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html