# Scala: value next is not a member of T compilation error

Tags: scala

Having the code:

```
class DoubleLinkedQueue[T] {
    class DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](value: T) {
        var next : DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T]
        var prev : DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T]
    }

    var head = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
    var tail = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
    head.next = tail //compillation error here

    def isEmpty() : Boolean = {
        return head.next == tail //and here
    }

    def peekStart() : T = {
        return head.next.value //and here too
    }

    def popStart() : T = {
        val result = peekStart()
        head.next = head.next.next //and everywhere when trying to acces head or tail properties
        return result
    }

    def peekEnd() : T = {
        return tail.prev.value
    }

    def popEnd() : T = {
        val result = peekEnd()
        tail.prev = tail.prev.prev
        return result
    }

    def pushStart(value : T) : DoubleLinkedQueue[T] = {
        val node = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](value)
        node.next = head.next
        node.prev = head
        head.next = node
        return this
    }

    def pushEnd(value : T) : DoubleLinkedQueue[T] = {
        val node = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](value)
        node.prev = tail.prev
        node.next = tail
        tail.prev = node
        return this
    }
}
```

and having the compillation error:

DoubleLinkedQueue.scala:9: error: value next is not a member of T => DoubleLinkedQueue.this.DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T]
    head.next = tail

Does anybody know how to fix it?

**UPD1** Is it the same issue that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305563/how-to-instantiate-an-instance-of-type-represented-by-type-parameter-in-scala)?

Comment: In `var head = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)`, head is of the type T=>DoubleLinkedQueueNode. `new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)`, is a partially applied function.

Comment: so how to make it type of DoubleLinkedQueueNode and leave DoubleLinkedQueueNode still generic?

Answer (score 0):

You can make value of DoubleLinkedQueueNode mutable:

```
class DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T] {
  var next : DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T] = _
  var prev : DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T] = _
  var value: T = _
}
```

So you don't need to initialize it with:

```
 var head = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
```

Instead you'll have:

```
 var head = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T]
```

Comment: hm... I could try. but it's looks like a bit semi-solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be, that a good solution is to use an Option as type of 'val' in DoubleLinkedQueueNode.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to create an instance of the DoubleLinkedQueueNode, you must give it a proper value of type T and not _.

When writing the following:

```
var head = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
```

You in fact create the following function:

```
T => DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T] = <function1>
```

So basically, its the same as writing:

```
var func = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
var head = func(someValueOfTypeT)
```

By the way, there are other issues i spot in the code, such as:

The second command can be erased:

```
var head = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
var tail = new DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](_)
head.next = tail //compillation error here
```

value should be val (as it is accessed in various methods in DoubleLinkedQueue)

```
class DoubleLinkedQueueNode[T](val value: T) {
```

Hope it helps.